# Setting Tracing On for apache camel

Tags: grails, log4j, apache-camel, trace

I want to test my integration test cases, for that i want to set my camel tracing on to debug my test cases.

how to do this in grails any idea? I am using log4j for logging.

Answer (score 0):

From Camel **2.12 onwards** you must explicit enable tracing on the `CamelContext`. The class contains `setTracing(Boolean enabled)` method.

So if you are using XML DSL:

```
<camelContext trace="true" ...>
```

otherwise:

```
camelContext.setTracing(true)
```

To setup logging is quite trivial I supposed.

Comment: Hi @milan-baran thanks for the reply, so do i need to set camelContext.setTracing(true) inside my testcase or inside setup, means where?

Comment: It depends, both options would work. I'd choose setup inside testcase.

Comment: oh right! thanks for the reply. anything needed to do in log4j in config.groovy for trace?

Comment: dunno, ensure your logger contains `org.apache` set to `trace` level.